# what function should I implement to cleanup the view of a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have A `UINavigationController` with a table view. As it's standard behaviour when an item in the list is selected I push a customViewController to the `UINavigationController`. The `CustomView` Appears and I see my back button in the title bar.

My question is, when I hit the back button in the title bar to navigate back to my list what function do I implement to make sure that everything that was created in the `customViewController` is completely destroyed and removed from memory?

I tried putting my cleanup code in the viewdidunload method of the custom controller but that doesnt even get entered when I hit the back button.

(Also I wasnt really sure how to phrase this question so suggestions are welcome)

Answer (score 0):

The `viewDidUnload` method of `UIViewController` seems to be a good place to do memory cleanup, i.e. release all objects that can be easily recreated in `viewDidLoad` or later.

But it's not guaranteed that the view controller itself will be dealloc'ed. The `UINavigationController` may cache the object internally.

Comment: The viewDidUnload was the first place I tried. I stuck a breakpoint in there and it doesnt get hit

Comment: Oh. I didn't see you mentioned that, sorry :/ If viewDidUnload is not called, that's strange...

Answer (score 0):

The allocated controllers inside a `UINAvigationController` will be removed automatically. If you need to let just one live, create the detail controller globally in your navigation controller instead every time you need to go to the detail view, so you will use always the same controller. You can clean it when the back button is pressed through the method **viewDidDisappear**.

Answer (score 0):

Apple explains everything very clearly in their [documenation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (with pretty pictures and everything!).  Basically, when you show the view you use `pushViewController:animated:` and when you go back you use `popViewControllerAnimated:`.

Use something like this to go to the new screen:

```
- (IBAction)goSomewhereButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    SomewhereViewController *vc = [[SomewhereViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomewhereView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

When the BACK button is pressed, it will clean-up your screen.  Apple recommends you use [UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UINavigationControllerDelegate) for additional setup & cleanup if needed.

Put the cleanup for the screen in its controller (`SomewhereViewController`).

```
    - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    NSLog(@"Somewhere's viewDidUnload called");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"Somewhere's dealloc called");
}
```

Comment: I guess my problem is that the dealloc function or the viewdidunload function in my customViewCOntroller is'nt actually getting called.... I don't understand why so maybe I need an alternative

Comment: Your controller's viewDidUnload and dealloc methods may not be called if some other object still has its hooks in your controller.  Add some log messages (or breakpoints) in viewWillDisappear: and/or viewDidDisappear: to verify they're being called.  I just had this problem because I started an NSTimer to periodically refresh my views contents; but the timer was continuing to fire after I left the view even though I invalidate it in viewDidUnload.  I had to invalidate it in viewWillDisappear:, then I saw my dealloc called.  Maybe you have a notification holding onto your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I always put my cleanup code in dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
   // cleanup code here
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: My dealloc is not being executed for some strange reason. I think I'm doing to have to manually call it from the didpopitem method but this is not ideal.

Comment: Make sure you release the controller after it gets pushed on to the navigation controller stack.  The navigation controller will retain it until it gets popped.